# LogOnUser() API failed if password has Greek characters

Tags: c#, windows, security

I am able to set Greek Password (Σιεμενσ123!) to windows user account using Computer Management. When I try to login with the Greek Password, the LogOnUser() API failed with  ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE(1326). Are there any invalid characters in this Greek Password? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Did you specify [`CharSet=CharSet.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-a-character-set)? Otherwise string marshaling defaults to `CharSet.Ansi`.

Comment: it worked. Thanks